# Recommended objective-c Math libraries for working with Quaternions Matrices Vectors etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I'm looking for a good Math library in objective-c that does your usual Matrix Vector and Quaternion tasks for use in conjunction with Core Animation. The library needs to be free for commercial use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a lightweight C++ linear algebra package which provides could matrix, vector and quaternion support.  While I have not used it in anger, it seems to have a much nicer interface than BLAS/LAPACK and supports a bunch of things those libraries don't

Answer (score 8):

Current versions of iOS include the [Accelerate Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html), which includes a large set of accelerated matrix math routines (BLAS, LAPACK, etc.)

Added:  You can also use any C math libraries/routines you might have, as Objective C is a compatible superset of ANSI C.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you find ObjectiveC math library. I use [vfpmathlibrary](http://code.google.com/p/vfpmathlibrary/)