# Is there any way to plot and analyse data with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, math, plot

I want to build an iOS application where you can easily view and interact with geophysics data (well logs, seismic sections etc), which usually come as huge matrices in SEGY format or similar.

Is there any way I can do this with swift? Also I need to extract statistics and and perform mathematical operations. Is there any scientific use of swift at all?

Sorry if I'm being vague, it's a fairly new idea and I would love to do it on iOS instead of using C/matlab/python etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing native to Swift, but you could always use third party frameworks for anything.

Of course, science power of Matlab won't be achievable by iOS, since the language is not intended for that, so you'll have to write some math functions on your own.

For charts, I used [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot), but now there's a better alternative written completely in Swift, called [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts).

Comment: Could you explain a bit what you mean by "use third party frameworks for anything"? Can I for example use python to process and display data, then use swift to allow the user to interact with the plots on an ipad?

Comment: Not python, but you can run c, c++, objective C and Swift code in iOS apps. There're plenty of math libraries written in C++ or C that can be ported to iOS, but it's not so simple (it can be done, but I don't recomend it). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938503/recommended-objective-c-math-libraries-for-working-with-quaternions-matrices-vec for some math libraries. Another good idea would be to process your data in another place (a middleware, like a server) and provide processed data to the iOS app, so it can show the carts and interact with them.

Comment: Sure, CorePlot (for Objective-C) and ios-charts (for both, ObjC and Swift) are really good alternatives. Both allow you to create different kind of charts with interactions depending on the kind of chart. I added links to CorePlot and ios-charts in my answer.